# Not able to draw rectangle on Wpf canvas from lower right corner to upper left corner

Tags: c#, wpf, rectangles

I am implementing functionality to allow user to draw rectangle on a Wpf canvas at run time by dragging mouse.I am currently able to able to draw the rectangle when I drag mouse from top left corner to bottom left, but the rectangle is not visible when I drag mouse from bottom left corner to top.Below is the xaml code that I am using:

```
<Canvas x:Name="CanvasContainer" MouseLeftButtonDown="CanvasContainer_MouseLeftButtonDown" MouseLeftButtonUp="CanvasContainer_MouseLeftButtonUp" MouseMove="CanvasContainer_MouseMove" >
   <Rectangle  x:Name="RectangleMarker" Canvas.Left="0"  Stroke="Red" Width="0" Height="0" Panel.ZIndex="1"></Rectangle>
   <Line x:Name="LineMarker"  Stroke="Red" X1="0" Y1="0" X2="0" Y2="0"></Line>
   <Image Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0"  x:Name="PdfImage" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" MouseWheel="PdfImage_MouseWheel"  ClipToBounds="True" Panel.ZIndex="0">
        <Image.LayoutTransform>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1"  CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5"  />
        </Image.LayoutTransform>
    </Image>
</Canvas>
```

Below are the event handling to update rectangle's position according to mouse position.

```
private void CanvasContainer_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {          
            Point startPoint = Mouse.GetPosition(CanvasContainer);
            Canvas.SetLeft(RectangleMarker, startPoint.X);
            Canvas.SetTop(RectangleMarker,startPoint.Y);      
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}

private void CanvasContainer_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {               
                Point endPoint = Mouse.GetPosition(CanvasContainer);
                Point startPoint = new Point((double)RectangleMarker.GetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty), (double)RectangleMarker.GetValue(Canvas.TopProperty));
                double x = Math.Min(startPoint.X, endPoint.X);
                double y = Math.Min(startPoint.Y, endPoint.Y);
                double width = endPoint.X - startPoint.X;
                double height = endPoint.Y - startPoint.Y;

                if (width < 0)
                {
                    x = startPoint.X + width;
                }
                if (height < 0)
                {
                    y = startPoint.Y + height;
                }
                RectangleMarker.Width = Math.Abs(width);
                RectangleMarker.Height = Math.Abs(height);
                if (x!=startPoint.X)
                {
                    Canvas.SetLeft(RectangleMarker, x);
                }
                else if(y!=startPoint.Y)
                {
                    Canvas.SetTop(RectangleMarker, y); 
                }                
        }          
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: @Sinatr I do not want to draw second rectangle, just want to move the existing rectangle.

Comment: @Sinatr I meant drawing rectangle like we do in paint tools. Press the mouse button and drag to draw the rectangle.If drag in the downward diagonal direction(UL to LR), then it works, but if we drag in upward diagonal direction(LR to UL) then the rectangle is not visible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Better use a Path with a RectangleGeometry:

```
<Canvas Background="Transparent"
        MouseLeftButtonDown="CanvasContainer_MouseLeftButtonDown"
        MouseLeftButtonUp="CanvasContainer_MouseLeftButtonUp"
        MouseMove="CanvasContainer_MouseMove">
    <Path Stroke="Red">
        <Path.Data>
            <RectangleGeometry x:Name="selectionRect"/>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
</Canvas>
```

Code behind:

```
private Point? startPoint;

private void CanvasContainer_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var element = (UIElement)sender;
    element.CaptureMouse();
    startPoint = e.GetPosition(element);
}

private void CanvasContainer_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    ((UIElement)sender).ReleaseMouseCapture();
    startPoint = null;
}

private void CanvasContainer_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (startPoint.HasValue)
    {
        selectionRect.Rect = new Rect(
            startPoint.Value, e.GetPosition((IInputElement)sender));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned earlier in comment your problem is not *drawing*, but **resizing**.

When resizing rectangle there are 4 possible directions, 4 sides and 4 corners. So it's kind of complicated.

The easiest way is to simply remember **start** mouse position and then check where is the **new** position, drawing rectangle between them. Obviously new mouse position can be either of corners, depending in which direction mouse was moved in relation to start point.

So:

```
Point _start;

void CanvasContainer_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) =>
    _start = Mouse.GetPosition(CanvasContainer);

void CanvasContainer_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
    {
        var mouse = Mouse.GetPosition(CanvasContainer);
        Canvas.SetLeft(RectangleMarker, _start.X > mouse.X ? mouse.X : _start.X);
        Canvas.SetTop(RectangleMarker, _start.Y > mouse.Y ? mouse.Y : _start.Y);
        RectangleMarker.Width = Math.Abs(mouse.X - _start.X);
        RectangleMarker.Height = Math.Abs(mouse.Y - _start.Y);
    }
}
```

`Math.Abs` will handle resizing for either positive or negative change, while for changing position we still need a conditional check to determine which point, start or new mouse, is the top-left corner.

Demo:

[image]

Comment: The only thing that I was missing was storing the starting point.Thanks.

Comment: "The easiest way..", not exactly. Even easier is to simply create a Rect from two Points. Regardless what exact corner each Point represents, the Rect will always be created correctly (as shown in my answer).

Comment: @Clemens, it's just wording. I like your solution. Though I can't see how to make mine easier. The aim was not to change too much (at least xaml).

Comment: I am using @Clemens solution as it requires lesser code in code behind file. But your solution also works.